# Populating observable array with jquery

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I'm trying to understand the knockout syntax and have the following question.

If I have the following view-model

```
var anotherObservableArray = ko.observableArray([
    { name: "Bungle", type: "Bear" },
    { name: "George", type: "Hippo" },
    { name: "Zippy", type: "Unknown" }
]);
```

the Array should be empty and not contain the hardcoded value as above.

I wants to populate this using jquery with this code

```
$.getJSON('api/market', self.markets);
```

How can i do that, and where should this getJSON code go?
Can anyone help me with a example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/json-data.html)

but basically it should look like this

```
$.getJSON("/some/url", function(data) { 
    anotherObservableArray(data);
})
```

assuming the data is a json array, otherwise set the observable to something like `data.arrayProperty` or whatever the array is stored as